# Invalid info plist value while uploading build contains share extension

Tags: ios

My app contain image share extension while uploading build got error somthing like invalid info plist but validating it does not show any error or message.

**code :**

```
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                   <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you change it NOT in the .plist file but in the Extention's info page (Between Resorce Tags and Build Settings)

[image: info .plist]